# Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for previously properly worked REST service

Tags: rest, http-status-code-405

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxx
```

**I get this error for the previously properly worked REST service.**

Does anyone have any idea how this happened?

Comment: Without seeing the url, the request and the server route handler (or api docs in case it's a third party): no.

Answer (score 0):

This means you're using an incorrect protocol, eg. using a POST call where you should use GET